# Modifying the scale of X axis in graph

Tags: stata

I'm trying to plot a graph in Stata. 
This is my code:

```
scatter logpgp95 avexpr || lfit logpgp95 avexpr, ylabel(4(2)10) xscale(range(4 10))
```

It gives me a graph like this:

[image: graph1]

I want a graph with X-axis starting at 4 and continuing to 10 and the 4 should be where the 2 is.

Something like this(as an example):

[image: graph2]

If I use the `xlabel` code only:

`scatter logpgp95 avexpr || lfit logpgp95 avexpr, ylabel(4(2)10) xlabel(4(2)10)`

I get this:

[image: graph3]

The problem is that I don't want 4 to be so far from the starting point.

Comment: Your `xsc()` option has no effect because you have data values for that axis below 4. You just need `xlabel(4(2)10)` like your `ylabel()` call and then no label for 2 will be shown. It is documented that "`range()` never narrows the scale of an axis or causes data to be omitted from the plot." See `help axis scale options`.

Comment: @NickCox edited my question to address your concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have a value below 2 for `avexpr` which has a missing value for `logpgp95` for the same observation. In this case the graph will still take that value as a minimum for the x axis but doesn't plot it as it doesn't have its y-value.

Try this:

```
scatter logpgp95 avexpr if !missing(logpgp95, avexpr) || lfit logpgp95 avexpr, ylabel(4(2)10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not reproducible.

I simulated some data with x axis range from 3.5 to 10. Even without asking the x axis labels appear as 4 6 8 10 and there is no enormous space to the left.

```
clear 
set obs 100 
set seed 2803 
range x 3.5 10 
gen y = x + rnormal()
scatter y x || lfit y x
```

I have to guess that your real code differs from what we can see. Other way round, we need your data to check what is happening.